# ggplot group by one categorical variable and color by a second one

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I'd like to create the first plot shown below in R using ggplot, but with both objects on the same graph (no facet wrapping).

Consider a minimal example that mimics my data structure:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1, 5, length = 100)
y <- replicate(10, sin(2 * pi * x) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.3), "list")
z <- replicate(10, sin(2 * pi * x) + rnorm(100, 5, 0.3), "list")
y <- melt(y)
z <- melt(z)
df <- data.frame(x = y$Var1, rep = y$Var2, y = y$value, z = z$value)
dat <- melt(df, id = c("x", "rep"))
```

I can plot it with

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x, value, group = rep, color = variable), 
    alpha = 0.3) + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

And get

[image]
<sub>(source: [carlboettiger.info](http://carlboettiger.info/assets/figures/2012-12-18-NA-unnamed-chunk-2.png))</sub>

But if I try dropping the facet wrapping, I thought it should group by color and variable, but instead the data are not broken out correctly, resulting in nonsense:

[image]
<sub>(source: [carlboettiger.info](http://carlboettiger.info/assets/figures/2012-12-18-NA-unnamed-chunk-3.png))</sub>

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that the `group` aesthetic overrides the standard grouping protocols - it isn't included in the *interaction of all discrete variables in the plot* described in [`?group`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html).

So, to get your plot to work without faceting you would need to manually specify the interaction

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x, value, group = interaction(rep,variable), color = variable), alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

To override the alpha value in the aesthetic, use `guide_legend(override.aes = ...))`. This information can be found following the links in [`?guides`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guides.html) and specifically [`?guide_legend`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html)

eg

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x, value, group = interaction(rep,variable), color = variable), 
                           alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic, thanks.  I do swear this used to work the way I tried above, e.g. grabbing a random example from my notes https://github.com/cboettig/pdg_control/blob/master/inst/examples/robustness/wrong_noise.md#add-discrete-classes-by-total-profit

Comment: Hmmm... There have been lots of bug fixes and at least one major rewrite of the group feature [see the NEWS](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS) -- The complete rewrite appeared to happen at version 0.5.

Comment: Oh, one more problem with this: Any idea how to make the legend not adopt the alpha transparency?  With lots of reps it's nice to have a low alpha but then the legend can't be read.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. There have been so many changes and additions in the most recent versions. The help for `guides`

Comment: @mnel can you comment on the answer supplied by EDi vs. your more `ggplot`-esque `interaction` function?

Comment: perfect, I'd give it +2 if I could.  & thanks for the guides links, those are very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could paste rep and variable a group:

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x, value, group = paste(variable, rep), color = variable), 
                    alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: `paste(variable, rep)` has the same outcome as `interaction(variable, rep)`, (more specifically `interaction(variable, rep, sep = ' ')` to produce exactly identical levels), as `ggplot` will coerce to `factor`, which will have identical levels (or at least levels which differ in label only) in both cases. IMO, the `interaction` route is clearer as it is clearer what you are trying to implement.