# ggplot individual densities with mean density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot densities from two different categories *as lines* and then the mean density of each category overlaid *as alpha*. Below is code to show the 'mean' densities only summarised over disease and treatment. How can I overlay this with lines representing the density for each individual (preferably red for disease = 1 and blue for disease = 2)? i.e. a line per disease, treatment combination in the example:

```
# Initialise data frame in melted form
    # 2 disease categories
    # 10 people from each disease
    # 2 treatments given to each individual
    # 25 variables with measured values per person/treatment combination
set.seed(6737334)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:(2*10*2*25), var = rep(1:25, times=2*10), 
                 val = rnorm(2*10*2*25),
                 disease = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=2*10*25)),
                 treat = as.factor(rep(1:2, times=10, each=25)))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=val, fill=disease)) + geom_density(alpha=.3) +
    facet_grid(treat ~ .)

print(plot)
```

[image: Image of ggplot produced by the above code]

################## EDIT

This code is very very close to my desired solution. How can I make the lines, currently black, match the colour of the disease category?

```
# Initialise data frame in melted form
    # 2 disease categories
    # 10 people from each disease
    # 2 treatments given to each individual
    # 25 variables with measured values per person/treatment combination
set.seed(6737334)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:(2*10*2*25), var = rep(1:25, times=2*10),
                 test = as.factor(rep(1:(2*10), each=25)),
                 val = rnorm(2*10*2*25),
                 disease = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=2*10*25)),
                 treat = as.factor(rep(1:2, times=10, each=25)))

ggplot(df) + 
    geom_density(aes(x=val, group=test, color=disease)) +
    geom_density(aes(x=val, fill=disease), color=NA, alpha=.5) +
    facet_grid(treat ~ .)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method turned out to be to utilise the `group` option of `aes()` with `interaction`. See full example below. Thank you to @Jaap above and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942844/ggplot-group-by-one-categorical-variable-and-color-by-a-second-one) for pointing in the right direction.

```
# Initialise data frame in melted form
    # 2 disease categories
    # 10 people from each disease
    # 2 treatments given to each individual
    # 25 variables with measured values per person/treatment combination
set.seed(6737334)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:(2*10*2*25), var = rep(1:25, times=2*10),
                 test = as.factor(rep(1:(2*10), each=25)),
                 val = rnorm(2*10*2*25),
                 disease = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=2*10*25)),
                 treat = as.factor(rep(1:2, times=10, each=25)))

ggplot(df) + 
    geom_density(aes(x=val, group=interaction(test,disease), colour=disease)) +
    geom_density(aes(x=val, fill=disease), alpha=.5) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="mean")) +     # else legend title 'NA'
    facet_grid(treat ~ .)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=val, color=disease)) +
  geom_density(aes(x=val), color=NA, fill="grey", alpha=.5) +
  facet_grid(treat ~ .) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Not quite. I'd like 10 lines and one 'fill' for each disease i.e. 20 lines and 2 fills on the plot. Each line corresponds to the density of a disease treatment combination.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to have put you on the right path. I didn't have the time to respond earlier. You can now accept your own answer.