# R ggplot2 plotting curves for percentages of counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, frequency-distribution

I intend to plot their percentage curves and two shaded curves for their averages.

The ggplot2 density plot did not present the percentages of counts on the Y-axis.

Here is a similar plot (code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888895/ggplot-individual-densities-with-mean-density)!).

How to plot the percentage "curves" with bins of a width of 10 that range from values the range on the x-axis?

How to add a small text indicates the round # on top of each curve and use different to indicate two species and use shaded area to indicate the average for two species?

[image]

Here is my dataset that can be reproduced in R:

```
  Virus <- c(rnorm(3000, mean = 40, sd = 0.3),rnorm(3000, mean = 41, sd = 0.5),rnorm(3000, mean = 38, sd = 1),rnorm(3000, mean = 39, sd = 1.3))
  Round <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 3000)
  Species <- rep(c(1,2), each = 6000)
  df <- data.frame(Virus, Round, Species)
```

Here is my code I tried:

```
  ggplot(df) + stat_bin(aes(x=Virus, group=interaction(Round,Species), colour=factor(Species)), alpha=1, binwidth=1, geom="line", position="identity") + aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)) + stat_bin(aes(x=Virus, group=Species, fill=factor(Species)), alpha=.4, binwidth=1, geom="bar", position="identity") + aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)) +  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Here is the result:

The shaded area seems just the sum of two curves. Please let me know how to plot the average of two curves for each species.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by providing plotting code and what you have tried.

Comment: Added. Thanks a lot. I just need some hints to plot frequency plot with curves.